# Rails plugin require issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I have a problem creating a Rails plugin, lets call it Mplug. The plugin is pretty much only a rake task, but with a library that the rake task uses.

The problem is to require files. Lets say that this is the rake task:

```
namespace :mplug do
  task :create do
    Mplug::Indexer.new
  end
end
```

This will not recognize the constant Mplug. So I thought I needed to require it.

```
require 'mplug'

namespace :mplug do
  task :create do
    Mplug::Indexer.new
  end
end
```

But then I get this message.

```
no such file to load -- mplug
```

So, ok. Lets try to give the path to the plugin then.

```
require 'vendor/plugins/mplug/lib/mplug'

namespace :mplug do
  task :create do
    Mplug::Indexer.new
  end
end
```

This actually works. However, except that I guess that this is a bad way to do it, I now have to require the files in my plugin as if I was in the rails root. For example:

```
module Mplug
end

require 'mplug/indexer'
```

Now has to be:

```
module Mplug
end

require 'vendor/plugins/mplug/lib/mplug/indexer'
```

Which I do not want to do of course.

Is there any neat way to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution to this problem would be to register the rake task using the Rails::Railtie API. In `lib/mplug.rb`, define your `Railtie`:

```
module Mplug
  class Railtie < ::Rails::Railtie
    rake_tasks do
      load "mplug/rails.rake"
    end
  end
end
```

Then, in `lib/mplug/rails.rake`:

```
namespace :mplug do
  task :create do
    Mplug::Indexer.new
  end
end
```

Then, make sure your plugin is defined in your `Gemfile`. If your plugin is in `vendor/plugins`, add this line to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem "mplug", :path => "vendor/plugins/mplug"
```

If you push the plugin to a git repo, use `:git`.

Now, `rake mplug:create` will be available! If you want it to show up in `rake -T`, make sure you add a description:

```
namespace :mplug do
  desc "creating an mplug"
  task :create do
    Mplug::Indexer.new
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the **FILE** constant, and then provide the rest of the path relative to the current file:

```
require File.join(File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)), '..', 'lib', 'mplug')
```

(if your rake task file is in your plugin_root/tasks...)

Comment: Well...

How then would the require statements in vendor/plugins/mplug/lib/mplug.rb be?

I still have to do like this in that file:
    require 'vendor/plugins/mplug/lib/mplug/indexer'

Comment: Most plugins use init.rb to require files when Rails boots up.
I suggest you review this Rails Guide:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html
It gives the best practices for structuring your rails plugin directories, init.rb, requires, etc.